# Django API, manage linked tabes using multiple GETs

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

In my django app i expose two tables using DjangoRestAPI for manage data one related to other.
There is a result data with this structure:

```
"results": [
{
  "id": 175194,
  "device": "f906e9db70b0cc822cb44ccd1b2b89a7",
  "res_key": "b865c3125cb4ef173e55377026d94b2b",
  "read_date": "2021-03-31T07:06:04.143569Z",
  "unit": 2
},
{
  "id": 21278,
  "device": "f906e9db70b0cc822cb44ccd1b2b89a7",
  "res_key": "c8a961f3ef9f8fa0ebdac3c910070055",
  "read_date": "2021-03-26T15:54:04.171926Z",
  "unit": 1
},
{
  "id": 25173,
  "device": "f906e9db70b0cc822cb44ccd1b2b89a7",
  "res_key": "75126c6b2b4e78fc553ec75c7eb927ea",
  "read_date": "2021-03-26T16:48:03.259185Z",
  "unit": 1
},
...
```

and a result_details API endpoint related to results:

```
"results_details": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "id_res": 236,
  "var_id": 1,
  "var_val": "[41]",
  "var_hash": "6f241d5445cf3031f6420de63c0a409bad527ea3"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "id_res": 326,
  "var_id": 1,
  "var_val": "[45]",
  "var_hash": "e5f03cfbed7ee88445b44ddf8e64365da310f8ec"
},
...
```

My models:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    res_key = models.SlugField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Message unique key", unique=True)
    read_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Datetime of vals readings")
    unit = models.ForeignKey(ModbusDevice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['device', 'unit']),
        ]


"""
Detailed vars results table 
"""
class VarsResults(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_res = models.ForeignKey(Results, related_name="mainres", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    var_id = models.ForeignKey(ModbusVariable, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    var_val = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    var_hash = models.CharField(max_length=400)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.var_hash

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['id_res', 'var_id']),
        ]
```

Here my serializers:

```
class ResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #main_res = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Results
        fields = ['id', 'device', 'res_key', 'read_date', 'unit']


class VarsResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id_res = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id_res.id')

    class Meta:
        model = VarsResults
        fields = ['id', 'id_res', 'var_id', 'var_val', 'var_hash']
```

there is an id_res field that link to main results data.
So, in this configuration, every time a user have to get results related to a specific device have to execute a GET to the first table filtering for device and then, inside a for loop, manage n GETs on second table passing the id for link to id_res.
If i find 100 rows from Results API call i have to execute 100 different calls to the Results_data.

Someone have an idea for better manage this king of situation from external API calls?
I try to avoid internal data aggregation, i would external apps after API call manage internally data structure.

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Show serializers and views.

Comment: Aded serializers, thanks

Comment: Models will be needed as well.

Comment: models added thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Django automatically adds `entity_id` column for foreign keys. It's not only a bad practice to add them manually but it might also break a few things.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column. (You can change this explicitly by specifying db_column) However, your code should never have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object.

2. `id` pk is also added automatically.
3. Your model names should be singular.

```
class Result(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    res_key = models.SlugField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Message unique key", unique=True)
    read_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Datetime of vals readings")
    unit = models.ForeignKey(ModbusDevice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['device', 'unit']),
        ]

class VarsResult(models.Model):
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result, related_name="mainres", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modbus_variable = models.ForeignKey(ModbusVariable, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    var_val = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    var_hash = models.CharField(max_length=400)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.var_hash

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['result', 'modbus_variable']),
        ]
```

4. Now if you pass `Result` instance to `ResultsSerializer` it will also return all its `mainres`.

```
class ResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mainres = VarsResultsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Results
        fields = ['id', 'device', 'res_key', 'read_date', 'unit', 'mainres']


class VarsResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VarsResults
        fields = ['id', 'id_res', 'var_id', 'var_val', 'var_hash']
```

5. You can take it a step further (I'm not sure what exactly do you need) and return all results from a single `Device`.

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='result_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['id', 'results']
```

6. Depending on your needs, read about `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.
   If you want to use view for `Result`, you should `Result.objects.prefetch_related('mainres').all()`

Answer (score 1):

Use django-rest-framework serializer to do it.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Read the doc, make some tests and your life will be simplify with django ;)

Change your serializer with :

```
class VarsResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id_res = ResultsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = VarsResults
        fields = ['id', 'id_res', 'var_id', 'var_val', 'var_hash']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i added in my question my serializers.

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR: It is redundant to specify `source='id_res'` on field 'ResultsSerializer' in serializer 'VarsResultsSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.